# TENGO PROBLEMAS CON LA FUNCIÓN PRINTER_OPNEN()

Tags: php, print

buenos días , os comento estoy intentando imprimir desde el dashboard en php directamente a mi impresora modelo MFC-L2705DW con la funcion printer_open() y me rebota un error el cual os dejo a continuacion: "**Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open()**"

alguna idea de porque me aparece?

el codigo escrito en php es el siguiente

```
<?php 
$handle = printer_open("MFC-L2705DW");
printer_start_doc($handle, "Demostracion");
printer_start_page($handle);
$font = printer_create_font("Arial", 100, 100, 400, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);
printer_draw_text($handle, 'This sentence should be printed.', 100, 400);
printer_delete_font($font);
printer_end_page($handle);
printer_end_doc($handle);
printer_close($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Has habilitado la extensión en el php.ini de tu servidor y lo has reiniciado? Si no funciona igual es porque la version del php_printer.dll no es compatible con tu versión de PHP.

Comment: Vale, te entiendo... una pregunta sabes de alguna alternativa @DSGDSR a implementar ??

Comment: Echale un vistazo a esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313439/printing-data-to-printer-using-php